how to represent null and true i json payload Python
I have a payload in my request against an endpoint having values null and true. In Pycharm I get red-dotted line below the two respectively. How can I "define null and true inside my json payloads setmethod in Python?
def setpayload_set():
myjson = {
    "hpsId": 10034,
    "powerPlants": null,
    "units": [{"componentId": 78111,
               "timeSeries": [{"name": "ts.start_bids_allowed",
                               "dtssId": "", "tsv": {"pfx": true,
                                                     "data": [[1723647600,
                                                               1]]}}]}]
          }
return myjson


In python you should use None istead of  null and True istead of  true in your JSON-like dictionary.
def setpayload_set():
    myjson = {
        "hpsId": 10034,
        "powerPlants": None, 
        "units": [
            {
                "componentId": 78111,
                "timeSeries": [
                    {
                        "name": "ts.start_bids_allowed",
                        "dtssId": "",
                        "tsv": {
                            "pfx": True,  
                            "data": [
                                [1723647600, 1]
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    return myjson

but if you wont to put null and true as the values then convert the python dictionary to Json string.
import json

json_payload = json.dumps(setpayload_set())
print(json_payload)

